# unable to concatenate value from another table ( using laravel 5.5)

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I am facing issue regarding storing ids and display their values from two different table i have 1 table business_master and other table is page_master i have combine business_name column with page_url column which are available on page_master table if i add my business and page first time its successfully combine these two values as one business can have many pages and if i only add page 2nd time i am unable to see business_url with page_url column:

My Page Model:

```
        class PageList extends Model
  {
 protected $table = 'page_master';


  protected $fillable = ['business_id', 'page_url', 'page_name'];


 public function business()
  {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Business','business_id');
  }

 }
```

and in my view:

```
<td>{{optional($value->business)->business_url}}.spikesales.io/{{$value->page_url}}</td>
```

This is my first time out if i add business_url and page_url

```
   hussain.spikesales.io/house
```

and then if i add only page the out put is something like that

```
   .spikesales.io/hello
```

My Controller looks like:

```
 public function pageListHere()
{
    $list = PageList::wherehas('business')->get();
    return view('page-list',compact('list'));
}
```

Your helo will be highly appreciated!

```
  class PageList extends Model
  {
protected $table = 'page_master';


protected $fillable = ['business_id', 'page_url', 'page_name'];



public function business()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Business','business_id');
}

  }
```

and my full view:

```
                                           @foreach($list as $value)
                                <tr>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="rwid" value="{{$value->id}}"/>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="{{$value->id}}" class="checkbox-custom" name="{{$value->id}}" type="checkbox"
                                               value="{{$value->id}}">
                                        <label for="{{$value->id}}" class="checkbox-custom-label"></label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""
                                           data-original-title="Tolltip">{{$value->page_name}}</p></td>
                                    <td>{{optional($value->business)->business_url}}.spikesales.io/{{$value->page_url}}</td>

                                    <td> {{$value->created_at}}</td>
                                    <td>

                                        <p>{{$value->coupon()->where('is_ordered','N')->count()}}/{{optional($value->particulars)->coupon_count}}</p>
                                    <div class="progress-bar">
                                        <span class="yello-proges" style="width:{{$value->coupon()->where('is_ordered','N')->count()}}%"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="ply-btn playpause">
                                        @if($value->is_live === 1)
                                            <span class="pause" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></span>
                                            <span class="play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
                                            <span class="spinner" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($value->is_live === 0)
                                            <span class="pause"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></span>
                                            <span class="play" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
                                            <span class="spinner" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
                                        @endif

                                            @if($value->is_live === Null)
                                                <span class="pause"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></span>
                                                <span class="play" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
                                                <span class="spinner" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
                                            @endif

                                    </button>
                                    {{--<a data-page-id="{{$value->id}}" class="ply-btn" id="playpause">--}}
                                        {{--<span class="pause"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></span>--}}
                                        {{--<span class="play" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>--}}
                                        {{--<span class="spinner" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>--}}
                                    {{--</a>--}}
                                    <div class="btn-group" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Action">
                                        <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle actinbtn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="{{url('edit-List/'.$value->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit Page</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="{{url('template/'.($value->particulars1)->id)}}" class="viewpage" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View Page</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dangrclr"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</a></li>
                                            {{--<li><a href="{{url('delete-list/'.$value->id)}}" class="dangrclr"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</a></li>--}}
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

Comment: Please share your other model, aswell the view.

Comment: Okay i have shared my model please see